# Integral $\int_0^1(1+e^{-x^2}) dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

How to integrate:

$$\int_0^1(1+e^{-x^2}) dx$$

I have tried it so many times, but couldn't find any clue
Please help

Comment: Do you know the error function ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\int_0^1 1+e^{-x^2}=\int_0^1 1+\int_0^1 e^{-x^2}=1+\int_0^1 e^{-x^2}$$
Now $$\int e^{-x^2}=\frac{\sqrt\pi\text{erf(x)}}{2}\implies I=1+\frac{\sqrt\pi\text{erf}(1)}2\approx 1.746$$
Where $$\text{erf(x)}=\frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}\int_0^x e^{-t^2} \,dt$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Use the Gaussian error function

$$erf(x) =\int \limits_{0}^{x}e^{-t^2}dt. $$